# Why isn't jquery's .position() the same as css's position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div of which "position" property is "absolute".

```
var a = $(div).first();

a.animate({top:20});

a.css("top");
>>"20px"

a.position().top;
>>15.243560791015625
```

What happened? The `.position()` gives me the position relative to the first positioned ancestor. Wouldn't it be the same as css's position?

**Edit**: or maybe I ask another question. How can I call `.animate` to make a.position().top === 20?

**Edit2**: found the bug. It's "rotate".

**Edit3**: for some reason, the `ui.position()` in jQuery UI plugin's callback works as `.css("top")`, not `.position()`. Although they have the same names.

Comment: .css('position') refers to the CSS property.

.position() refers to the coordinates of the element on the page.

Comment: Yes. But why are they different?

Comment: when css's position is "absolute", the "top" is relative to it's closest positioned ancestor, right? And the .position() return a relative position to it's closest positioned ancestor?

Comment: @Lai Could you post a jsfiddle? It works quite fine for me...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PWhQV/2/ This jsfiddle works just fine for me. Did you happen to run the second statement in the middle of the animation?

Comment: @Lai Yu-Hsuan:  Regarding your "edit2" - That's not really a bug; It's more like you totally misunderstood what was going on with your `rotate`.

Comment: I don't consider it a bug. I'm working on other's web page and I carelessly missed the "-webkit-transform" property. I thought the rotating effect is just png transparent. It's my fault.

Answer (score 6):

jQuery's `position` is relative to the offset parent ([source](http://api.jquery.com/position/)). Using jQuery's `offset` is relative to the document ([source](http://api.jquery.com/offset)) which should produce the same number if you're element has a fixed position

Comment: is trying to explain your question and the fact that `.position()` is about `.offset()`. @antisanity: It appears not.

Comment: Don't understand. `.offset()` is the relative position to document. `.position()` is the relative position to offset parent. css's left is the relative position to close positioned parent when 'position:absolute'. So why it's about `.offset()`?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for wasting your time... I looked around my css style and found the problem.

The problem is caused by "rotate".

When an element is rotated, it's `.position()` would be changed but css not.

So they are different.

Anyway, thank you all for answers.